# Error when installing Python scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having trouble installing scikit-learn for Python 3.6 on my machine.

It's a Windows 10, 64 bit OS with (now) admin rights.I tried the same before without admin rights but got the same error:

Command

> "c:\users\programmieren\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qn_ag9lu\scikit-learn\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-kht7j77k-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qn_ag9lu\scikit-learn\

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: Consider asking this question @[SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been able to get it installed using a regular distribution of Python personally.

You can install it by installing Anaconda, which includes scikit-learn, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, and a bunch of other modules that are difficult to install on Windows.

Anaconda will install a brand new distribution of Python, which you'll have to use to import the modules.

Here's the link:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows

Comment: Like you said, Anaconda will get it done. Downloaded and installed it and it was working perfectly from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens generally while using windows. If you want to install any advanced python libraries for windows kindly the this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

For your problem, kindly download the scikit-learn library from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn).

Then do a `pip install <downloaded scikit-learn whl file>`

Comment: Wow this really helped. Is there an explanation as to why pip install scikit-learn fails?

Comment: @Veeraraghavan Few Python libraries are not compatible with the most recent official CPython distributions on Windows >=6.0.